# Android permissions - Broad Classification?

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there a broad classification of all the permissions in Android? For instance the below permissions are all related to Location

```
ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION 
ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS
ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION
```

In the same way are all the permissions grouped into based on the type?

Comment: yes they are, for sending receiving messages, reading writing sd cards and much more.

Comment: Can you point me to a place where I can see this classification?

Comment: this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html summarise all permission of android !